# When does the activeworkbook/activesheet change?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some questions about the activeworkbook/activesheet properties, would appreciate your help:

1. In any instances, there would be at maximum only one activeworkbook or no, and that applies to activesheet. Is that right?
2. If properties like ranges,cells,... are not fully qualified when used, they are by default meant to be that of the activeworkbook.activesheet. Is that right?
3. Will the activeworkbook change to another workbook by vba actions other than activating the other workbook?
4. When I use wb.ws.range(cells(x1,y1),cells(x2,y2)), are the cells implied to be the cells of wb.ws? Or do they need to be qualified?
5. Is it possible to run the vba codes stored in the modules of a workbook without activating the workbook?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In any instances, there would be at maximum only one activeworkbook or no, and that applies to activesheet. Is that right?

Yes. `.ActiveWorkbook` returns a `Workbook` object that represents the workbook in the active window (the window on top).

> If properties like ranges,cells,... are not fully qualified when used, they are by default meant to be that of the activeworkbook.activesheet. Is that right?

Yes

```
Debug.Print rng.Parent.Name '<~~ This will give you the name
```

> Will the activeworkbook change to another workbook by vba actions other than activating the other workbook?

Yes it is possible. For example if you send your Active Workbook to `Back` or minimise it then if the next window in [zOrder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264849.aspx) is a workbook then that will get activated

> When I use wb.ws.range(cells(x1,y1),cells(x2,y2)), are the cells implied to be the cells of wb.ws? Or do they need to be qualified?

Only if ws is active then yes else they will refer to `Activesheet` and hence it is always good to fully qualify your objects

```
With ws
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(x1, y1), .Cells(x2, y2))
End With
```

> Is it possible to run the vba codes stored in the modules of a workbook without activating the workbook?

Yes. You can use `Application.Run`

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: about answer3, so does it mean that the activeworkbook changes only by methods that deactivate the current one? Methods called by another workbook does not activate it besides the activate one?

Comment: Would you tell more about how a workbook can be sent to back using vba? Thanks.

Comment: Active Workbook can change because of many reasons `1` Your code changes it by directly shifting focus on another workbook `2` Your code indirectly shifts focus on another workbook. And this happens when you say "minimize" the currect active workbook. A workbook (window) can be sent back using the API `SetWindowPos` If you search google you will find lot of references on it. My favourite site for APIs is [AllAPI](http://allapi.mentalis.org)